# Correctly evaluating string equivelance and dealing with nulls

Tags: java, string

When using the equal method, if the string being compaired is null it results in an error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nullString = null;
    String nullString2 = null;
    System.out.println(nullString.equals(nullString2));
}
```

Result:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)

This is causing a problem with what I want to do because I need to evaluate Strings and using the == operator frequently causes equivelant strings to evaluate as false.

In my actual application if I have the following code as part of a loop this is the output I get:

```
System.out.println(pointPerson == storyTasks.get(i).getPointPerson());
if (pointPerson != null) {
    System.out.println(pointPerson.equals(storyTasks.get(i).getPointPerson()));
}
```

false
true
false
true

So how can I prevent the program from crashing but also correctly evaluate strings.

I will be doing the evaluation as part of a long if statement in my actual program:

```
                        if (!name.equals(storyTasks.get(i).getName())
                                || !desc.equals(storyTasks.get(i)
                                        .getDescription())
                                || !est.equals(storyTasks.get(i)
                                        .getOriginalEstimate())
                                || !taskStatus.equals(storyTasks.get(i)
                                        .getStatus())
                                || !pointPerson.equals(storyTasks.get(i)
                                        .getPointPerson())) {
                             //code
                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StringUtils.equals()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple helper method:

```
public static boolean equalsOrNull(Object o1, Object o2)
{
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return true;
    if (o1 == null) return false;
    if (o2 == null) return false;
    return o1.equals(o2);
}
```

Comment: @Vandel said it simply : `(str1==null ? str2==null : str1.equals(str2))`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) (since Java 7)

If you want to write the [method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.equals%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) yourself to support earlier versions of Java :

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```